# Is it possible to transfer type to C++ method or determine type in the method?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a list of data of any type by myself, and I want to print this list based on the data type. At this point, I have tested integers and characters. To print a list of these types, there are two methods `print_int` and `print_char`, depending on the data type being displayed. My question is, is it possible to define only one method `print` that will print depending on the data type of my list without creating a class template (unlike `List<type> ...`)?
I mean without this class definition:

```
template <class T>
class List{
  T *data;
  List *next;
  ...
```

**-------------------------- UPDATE--------------------------**

Finally, I found a solution that gives me the ability to dynamically check the type in C++ (using `dynamic_cast`, see the accepted answer). Unfortunately, many people mistakenly believe that C++ is severely limited. Which demonstrates my question, to which many, not knowing the answer, put minuses.

Comment: General Rule of Thumb:  When the data type changes, but the algorithm doesn't, consider using a `template`.

Comment: Yes you use templates. You need a print function that accepts any type and it will print that type automatically. It already exists. `operator<<()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews Does this mean that the only solution is to avoid `void *` and use the class template?  https://stackoverflow.com/users/14065/martin-york - again `operator<<()` needs to convert `void*`

Comment: Regarding "_undefined reference to `void List::print<int>()`_": This might help: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: My understanding is that you'll need to have a field that is either a type indicator or a pointer to a print function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews - yes, maybe a new attribute as type indicator is a solution. I first tried going to the same type in `print`

Comment: It's possible using `void*`, but difficult to get right and make safe. If you absolutely must have the type unknown at compile time and known at runtime, consider using `std::variant` or `std::any` rather than trying to do it all manually.

Comment: Thank you @aschepler. `std :: any` is very interesting and might be a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, many people mistakenly believe that C++ is severely limited. Which demonstrates my question, to which many, not knowing the answer, put minuses. Luckily, I found a solution/answer that gives me the ability to **dynamically check the type in C++** using `dynamic_cast`. So using `if (dynamic_cast<TypeToCheck*>(data))` you can check the `data` type (is it equal to type `TypeToCheck`?). Unfortunately, this only works for class types.

I think it's helpful, so here's the implementation:

The list class (`list.h`):

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
};


class Char : public Base {
    char value;
public:
    Char(char value) : value(value) {};

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, const Char* self) {
        return stream << "'" << self->value << "'";
    };
};


class Int : public Base {
    int value;
public:
    Int(int value) : value(value) {};

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, const Int* self) {
        return stream << self->value;
    };
};


class Float : public Base {
    float value;
public:
    Float(float value) : value(value) {};

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, const Float* self) {
        return stream << self->value;
    };
};


class List
{
    Base* data = nullptr;
    List* next = nullptr;
public:
    List() {};
    List(Base* data):data(data) {};

    void set_next(List* next) {this->next = next;};

    void append(Base* data) {
        List *last_element = this;
        while(last_element->next)
            last_element = last_element->next;

        last_element->set_next(new List(data));
    };

    void print_element(){
        if (dynamic_cast<Char*>(data))
            std::cout << (Char*)data << "(Char)";
        else if (dynamic_cast<Int*>(data))
            std::cout << (Int*)data << "(Int)";
        else if (dynamic_cast<Float*>(data))
            std::cout << (Float*)data << "(Float)";
    }
    void print() {
        bool is_first = true;
        
        cout << endl << "list " << static_cast<void*>(this) << " [";

        List* element = this;
        while(element) {
            if (is_first)
                is_first = !is_first;
            else
                cout << ", ";
            element->print_element();
            element = element->next;
        }
        cout << "]" << endl;
    };
};
```

Testing file (`main.cpp`):

```
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    List myList(new Int(10));
    myList.append(new Float(1.203f));
    myList.append(new Int(12));
    myList.append(new Char('f'));
    
    myList.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Result is:

```
list 000000000014F6D8 [10(Int), 1.203(Float), 12(Int), 'f'(Char)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store *any* type in a list without losing type information, you might try a polymorphic approach, too:

```
class NodeBase
{
public:
    virtual ~NodeBase();
    virtual void print() = 0;

    template <typename T>
    void append(T t);

protected:
    NodeBase* next;

    void appendNode(NodeBase* node);
};

template<typename T>
class Node : public NodeBase
{
public:
    void print() override { ... }

private:
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
void NodeBase::append(T t) // as being template, needs to remain in header!
{
    appendNode(new Node<T>(t));
}
```

Finally the `print` implementation might use different overloads of another function to actually print the `data` value.

Side note: I'd prefer to rename the current `List` class to `Node` and make it an inner class of a newly created `List` class which would manage the nodes internally. The current list implementation can easily result in memory leaks if you move the only pointer to head to a successor of.

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer might look like what I want (especially for the remaining templates in the header). Could you please explain more precisely how to use your Node object?

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin There's not too much to tell about. The new nodes would be used exactly as your variant, the `NodeBase` class would retain all the implementation your original variant hat *but* two details: Storage of the specific data object and the object-specific functionality like printing it. This specific behaviour you make accessible to the base class via virtual functions (a core feature of polymorphism) – and that's it...

Comment: Thanks again! I ended up making an implementation of a list of different types. But I'm not sure if this is optimal and I have a problem with the implementation of the destructor (which is why I commented it).

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin You might then open a chat room and invite me to – we could discuss your implementation in detail there.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very simple list!

```
template <class T>
class List{
   T*    data;
   List* next;

   void print() {
       std::cout << "[ ";
       print(this, "");
       std::cout << " ]\n";
   }
   void print(List* node, std::string const& sep) {
       if (node == nullptr) {
           return;
       }
       std::cout << sep << node->data;
       print(node->next, ", ");
   }
}
```

That should work for any type that supports normal stream output. Now this should get you going but I would change how you implement list a lot. Think of a list as the owner of a set of nodes. The nodes hold the data but are not the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I don't want to use the class template, because in the case of type `void *` for `data`, we can mix integers, characters, strings, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin: In that case, you've erased the type, and therefore should not have any type specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a different approach:  pointers to print functions.
Let's create a synonym for a print function:

```
typedef (void) (*(Ptr_Print_Function)(std::ostream& output, void * node_data));
```

Since each node can be of a different type, something will have to initialize the print function correctly.

```
struct Node
{
  void * p_data;
  Node * prev_node;
  Node * next_node;
  Ptr_Print_Function p_printer;
};
```

Here are some addition forwarded declarations:

```
void Print_Integer_Node(std::ostream& output, void * p_data);
void Print_Char_Node(std::ostream& output, void * p_data);
```

Here's a code fragment for printing the node to `std::cout`:

```
Node * p_node;
//... node search / initialize
(p_node->p_printer)(std::cout, p_node->p_data);
```

**Edit 1:  Data Inheritance**
IMHO, a cleaner method is to use inheritance and a base (interface) class for the data.

```
struct List_Data_Interface
{
    virtual void print_data(std::ostream& output) = 0;
    void * p_data;
};

struct Node_Version_2
{
    List_Data_Interface * p_data;
    Node_Version_2 *      p_prev;
    Node_Version_2 *      p_next;
};
```

In the above model, we are assuming that the data for every node has a print method and a pointer to some data.

A sample integer data:

```
struct Integer_Data : public List_Data_Interface
{
  void print_data(std::ostream& output)
  {
      int * p_int_data = (int *) p_data;
      output << *p_int_data;
  }
};
```

Here's some code on how to print a node using the above `Node_Version_2`:

```
//...
Node_Version_2 p_node;
//... initialize or find the node.
p_node->print_data(std::cout);
```

Through *polymorphism* the correct print function will be chosen.

Comment: IMHO, you should throw away the concept of `void *`, unless as a last resort (like loosing your foot kind of last resort).  Use a base interface class instead.  A base interface class is easier to use with polymorphism.  Let the child class define the functionality of the interface.